# Partition by hash on two levels

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm trying to partition a large table by a generated ID(unfortunately it's a mongoDB, so the first few bytes are not evenly distributed)

I would like to shard it (using a foreign data wrapper) on this ID.
Then within the shard partition again on this ID.

How can I set up the hash so that the within the shard so that the data is evenly distributed?

If we could use a function like RIGHT, I would shard by the 24th char, then partition by the 23rd. Or if it was a UUID, i'd would do the same but with char1, and char2.

Comment: You tagged this as postgresql, but you mentioned MongoDB? Could you clarify please?

Comment: this is a postgres 12 implementation.  however, years ago, we where using mongodb. and even though we moved off of it, we are stuck with mongodb id's for over 1m users, who where customers before we moved to postgres.  new customers get a UUID for an user_id, but we can't migrate the old users since some of them use there ID's to call our API's.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the wisdom of two levels of hash partitioning — if I were you, I would not partition the individual shards. But perhaps you have a compelling reason to do that.

You could use this for the fist level of partitioning:

```
PARTITION BY HASH (id)
```

and for the second level, you could use

```
PARTITION BY HASH (reverse(id::text))
```